# Wanted to Change the the EC2 instance ip address in Route53

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-route53

I have domain with godaddy and hosted the application in AWS EC2 instance which managing the traffic through route53. There is a need to change the EC2 instance to deploy the application with the different public IP address. If i change the "A" type record with the new EC2 instance ip address, will it work to manage the traffic through new IP address?

Comment: Does the route53 have the old ec2 ip addess as A record?

Comment: yes,currently it has old ec2 ip address as A record

Comment: In that case yes please update the new EC2 public ip

Answer (score 1):

Yes of course you can update the A type record any time, but it will take some time to propagate considering the TTL value of the record.

But using public IP to direct traffic to instances is a major anti-pattern for any type of deployment. Pointing traffic to an Elastic Load Balancer and distribute traffic from there will be a much scalable solution. The biggest advantage you have there is, no longer need to change the A record in Route 53 every time you deploy a new EC2 instance.